Wired Mbus Master long distance
I want to read long distance at 2400 baud speed. I designed the master and slave device. The slave device draws 1.34 mA from the line. While the master device performs reading from a short distance, it does not perform reading from a long distance when 1 device is connected. However, I can read when the number of devices is more than 1. What could be the reason for this?
I would like to find a theoretical explanation of this problem.

What exactly is "long distance" for you? Depending on the baudrate there are limitations to the absolute distance covered. Lower baudrate can cover longer distances. You can use repeaters to refresh the signal. I know of cases where other physical transports (like optical fibres) can be used to extend the total length.
Have a look here for some phyiscal limitations: https://m-bus.com/documentation-wired/04-physical-layer
